# Choice for building a online bulk mail sending system?

Tags: php, python, email, smtp, sendmail

I am sorry that there is some similar topic exists, but they are asked a long time ago.
So allow me to open a new thread for asking this.

Recently i am asked to build a online bulk mailing system . The mail is approved and subscribed. I found that phplist is exactly what i want but unfortunely i have to do a system by myself.

I have some experience in php python so i am considering whether i build it by

1. [php](http://www.php.net/)
2. [python](http://python.org/)
3. Other option that is easier

Then , i have to select some component to facilitate my job
As i can see so far, there are few choices for me:

1. phpmailer
2. pear

So, my question is which is better( as phpmailer seems can not send bulk mail)? Building my own smtp server is highly not recommended??? but if i use free smtp such as google it only allow 500 mail a day.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you possibly integrate with a API of a Service like [Mailchimp](http://www.mailchimp.com/)? Realize you said you have to roll your own but you could off load all the worries of sending mail to them. So you don't have to worry and can just focus on your application.

**Probably not the Answer you are looking for more of a suggestion.**